# How to add slash "/" as part of project number string in Href like 18074/1 ? it consider it as directory result 404 error Not Found. My Code Attached

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, href

I am having error while updating some record and my project number that is of string type contains slash for `example:  18074/1`

My code in ajax call i am actually appending as string and than display resource as HTML.

Part of code,

```
output += ' | <a href="/Home/UpdateProject/' + result[i].Project_Number + '" class="label label-warning">Update</a> ';
```

Href link after execution is like,

```
http://../Home/UpdateProject/18074
```

Above link is working fine it is calling controller action for update project.

But some times my project id has "/"

```
http://../Home/UpdateProject/18074/1
```

Here
`18074/1` is my project number but in url it is acting like `18074` separately and `/` as directory link

resulting in 404 Not found error

Comment: You can pass the project number through [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode it for URL usage

Comment: If you only have 1 then you could add it as a second route and combine in the controller.

Comment: @Syed Mohsin: Can you include to the post all parts of the view code related to you issue (model definition and Ajax call), please?